# .NET 6 C# get result from List<Task> not working

Tags: c#, task, .net-6.0

I have a part of my ASP.NET Core 6 API where I'm connecting with another service. This is a bulk operation (perhaps 2 to 4 operations top) and I want to perform it in parallel.

In order to achieve this, I'm trying to take advantage of tasks, like this:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach(var item in items)
{
    tasks.Add(PerformTask(item));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

foreach(var task in tasks)
{
    task.Result;
}
```

But when I try to get result from each task, the "Result" property doesn't exist.

What am I missing?

Comment: `var results = await Task.WhenAll(items.Select(PerformTask));`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Result` is property of generic [`Task<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=net-7.0). If `PerformTask` returns `Task` of some type then create `List<Task<TypeReturnedByPerformTask>>`. Also you will be able to fetch the results without `.Result` call (there is a [generic overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-7.0#system-threading-tasks-task-whenall-1(system-threading-tasks-task((-0))())) of `Task.WhenAll` which returns `Task` of array of result type):

```cs
List<Task<TypeReturnedByPerformTask>> tasks = ...;
// ...
TypeReturnedByPerformTask[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the piece I was actually missing!